# Non-EU student in Spain to Ph.D. internship in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, spain, internship

I am a no-EU Ph.D. student in Spain. I have received an internship offer from Huawei, Munich, Germany to do a Ph.D. research internship for 5 months.
At moment, I hold a Spanish work visa and residence card untill 2023, I wanted to ask can I apply for a German research visa while keeping my Spanish work visa and residence card?